# DNA Structure and Function

Tags: dna

In a strand of DNA, why does identifying the 3' side and the 5'side matter? Or the 3' --> 5' strand and the 5' --> 3' strand? Also, what is a single strand of DNA called, is it just a helix, or is the helix just the backbone?

Comment: These are basic questions that a careful reading of a textbook can answer. If you post to this list you need to show evidence of having made an effort to find the answer to the question. I suggest you refer to Wikipedia or, better, texts available in NCBI bookshelf and then edit your question. The link is: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/?term=dna+structure. Biochemistry by Berg et al., Molecular Biology of the Cell by Alberts et al., or Molecular Cell Biology by Lodish et al. are all well-written and authoratitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A double strand is a helix, as the basepairs move with a horizontal angle with each step to the next basepair. Identifying the sides is important for DNA-replication and RNA synthesis as the way DNA is read is from 3' to 5' so that the complementary bases can be ''glued'' together from 5' to 3' in which the phosphate groups bind to the OH groups of the other molecule by a polymerase reaction. 
Disregard first answer.

There.

Answer (score 4):

Well, a single strand of DNA is called a denatured chain ... Basically, it has the structure of RNA

Answer (score 0):

A single strand is a helix, as the basepairs move with a horizontal angle with each step to the next basepair. Identifying the sides is important for DNA-replication and RNA synthesis as the way DNA is read is from 3' to 5' so that the complementary bases can be ''glued'' together from 5' to 3' in which the phosphate groups bind to the OH groups of the other molecule by a polymerase reaction.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. When you answer a question here you need to back up your assertions with references. Otherwise nobody can determine whether or not they are correct. In this case you are certanly incorrect in stating that "a single strand is a helix". There is no reason for a single strand of DNA to adopt a helical conformation and it is unlikely to do so. It certainly will not adopt the double-helical formation as that requires base-pairing between two strands.